# Which class should store the lookup table?

Tags: python, oop

The world contains agents at different locations, with only a single agent at any location. Each agent knows where he's at, but I also need to quickly check if there's an agent at a given location. Hence, I also maintain a map from locations to agents. I have a problem deciding where this map belongs to: `class World`, `class Agent` (as a class attribute) or elsewhere.

In the following I put the lookup table, `agent_locations`, in `class World`. But now agents have to call `world.update_agent_location` every time they move. This is very annoying; what if I decide later to track other things about the agents, apart from their locations - would I need to add calls back to the world object all across the `Agent` code?

```
class World:
  def __init__(self, n_agents):
    # ...
    self.agents = []
    self.agent_locations = {}
    for id in range(n_agents):
      x, y = self.find_location()
      agent = Agent(self,x,y)
      self.agents.append(agent)
      self.agent_locations[x,y] = agent
  def update_agent_location(self, agent, x, y):
    del self.agent_locations[agent.x, agent.y]
    self.agent_locations[x, y] = agent
  def update(self): # next step in the simulation
    for agent in self.agents:
      agent.update() # next step for this agent
  # ...

class Agent:
  def __init__(self, world, x, y):
    self.world = world
    self.x, self.y = x, y
  def move(self, x1, y1):
    self.world.update_agent_location(self, x1, y1)
    self.x, self.y = x1, y1
  def update():
    # find a good location that is not occupied and move there
    for x, y in self.valid_locations():
      if not self.location_is_good(x, y):
        continue
      if self.world.agent_locations[x, y]: # location occupied
        continue
      self.move(x, y)
```

I can instead put `agent_locations` in `class Agent` as a class attribute. But that only works when I have a single `World` object. If I later decide to instantiate multiple `World` objects, the lookup tables would need to be world-specific.

I am sure there's a better solution...

EDIT: I added a few lines to the code to show how `agent_locations` is used. Note that it's only used from inside `Agent` objects, but I don't know if that would remain the case forever.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to update `Agent.agent_locations` regardless? How "quickly" must your quick check be? How many agents do you have? If you don't have that many (relative), you could just iterate over a World's agents, checking their locations.

Comment: When the agent decides where to move, he checks to make sure he doesn't run into other agents. If I iterate over all agents to check that, I would end up looking up each agent's location (performing `n_agents` operations) whenever any agent moves. Updating lookup table takes only one operation per `move`.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't check that though? `update_agent_location` just overwrites whoever was at `(x,y)` before... Anyway, would moving the lookup table to the `Agent` class really solve anything? Wouldn't you still have to call `Agent.update_agent_location`?

Comment: Let me add a sample code to show how I use it. I just didn't include it originally to keep it shorter. As for moving it to `Agent`, it would at least keep everything contained in the `Agent` class. My main concern is that `Agent` objects are helping another class maintain some lookup table that they know little about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps with OOP to talk about the objects in terms of *is a* and *has a*.  A `World` *has a* list of `Agents` and a list of `Locations`.  A `Location` *has an* `Agent`.  An `Agent` *has a* `Location` and a `World`.

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, world):
        self.location = None
        self.world = world

    def move(self, new_location):
        if self.location is not None:
            self.location.agent = None
        new_location.agent = self
        self.location = new_location

    def update(self):
        for new_location in self.world.locations:
            if self.location_is_good(new_location):
                self.move(new_location)

    def location_is_good(self, location):
        if location.agent is not None:
            return False

class Location:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.agent = None
```

Go through the mental exercise of adding a new attribute to a `Location`, such as terrain, and it's easy to see the benefits of such encapsulation.  Likewise, adding new things to `Agent`, such as a weapon, just requires a weapon-specific function similar to `move()`.  Note that the `World` doesn't need to get involved in the `move()` at all.  The move is handled strictly between the `Agent` and the `Location`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be dangerous to have the lookup table stored in one class (`Location`) but updated from another (`Agent`)? I always tried to avoid touching internals of one class from another.

Comment: It's actually a [pretty common paradigm](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#odds-and-ends) in python.  The convention is to prefix data members with an underscore if you don't want them used that way.  You could always add `get_agent()` and `set_agent()` methods to `Location` and use those instead but it doesn't gain you anything in security.  Getter and setter methods are mainly used in Java and C++ to prevent people from subclassing in unsupported ways.  The python culture is more be polite and trust others but do crazy things at your own risk.

Comment: I didn't realize that, and was imitating C++/Java style getter/setter paradigm with Python. Still, while I have no problem accessing lookup table from another class, I'm a bit concerned. For example, any change to the desired behavior of the lookup table will require changes in code all over my project, and not just in `class Location`.

Comment: Needing to change the behavior of something as simple as a two-way map sounds suspiciously like [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it) territory, but you could put `move()` in the `Location` class instead, if you're going to have that many things moving around between locations, but it will sacrifice some readability.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I can provide my answer, which is perhaps more an opinion than a definitive "do this" (I don't have any formal training in programming).

**I think you `agent_locations` should be a member of each `World` instance.**

I try to think in terms of interface primarily. In my view, the World class should be responsible for managing the resources of your world, in this case space. Since `World` is the manager of space, Agents should ask their *world* if space is available (i.e. unoccupied), not each other. Therefore, I think your `self.location_is_good` call more appropriately would be `self.world.is_location_available(x, y)` [1]

This makes it natural for the world to be responsible for looking up the availability of the given space. The World class might furthermore have other variables deciding whether a space is available. What if there's a shrubbery there? Or something. You probably already have some kind of table for your `(x, y)` coordinates on each world. Being "occupied" can be a property of those objects.

Furthermore: Your World already knows the state of every agent (by `[(agent.x, agent.y) for agent in self.agents]` [2]). The `agent_locations` dict is essentially an index or cache for these properties, which therefore belongs to `World`.

Regarding the pain of sending state back to the `World`... well, you're not going to solve that by making `Agent` do it instead. But doing `update_agent_location(self, agent, x, y)` is completely superfluous, since `x == agent.x; y == agent.y` (if you reverse the lines where you call it). You could simply have one method in World, `update_agent_state(self, agent)`, which World can use to update its indices. You might even submit an extra param to describe the type of state change (if you don't want to update all the properties eveytime).

```
class World(object):
  # ...
  def update_agent_state(self, agent, state_change=None):
    # Update properties based on what changed, or
    # drop state_change param and update everything everytime
    if state_change == Agent.LOCATION_CHANGE:
      self.agent_locations[agent.x, agent.y] = agent
    elif state_change == Agent.WHATEVER:
      pass

class Agent(object):
  LOCATION_CHANGE = 1

  def update(self):
    for x, y in self.valid_locations():
      if not self.can_move_to(x, y)
        continue

      self.move(x, y)

  def can_move_to(self, x, y):
    """Determines if x, y is a location where we can move."""
    if not self.world.is_location_available(x, y):
      return False
    if not self.has_money_to_travel_to(x, y):
      return False

    return True

  def move(self, x, y):
    """Moves to x, y and notifies world of state change."""
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

    self.world.update_agent_state(self, Agent.LOCATION_CHANGE)
```

Something like that (read my footnotes).

[1] Unless, of course, "goodness" of a location depends upon other variables than if the space is free. E.g. if you should only move to (x, y) if 1) the location is available and 2) the agent has 1000 $ to pay for a ticket, then you should have a `Agent.can_move_to(x, y)` which in turn calls the world's method, and checks its wallet.

[2] I'm assuming your `self.agents = {}` is a typo, since you can't `append` on a dict. You mean a list (`[]`) right?

Comment: 1) Thanks, fixed the typo. 2) `update_agent_location` is not redundant because it needs to know both the previous and the new coordinates (otherwise it can't delete the old record). 3) I agree I'm not solving any coding annoyance by moving to `Agent` class, but at least it all stays contained in one class, so it's easier to make sure it's all consistent. 4) I like your idea that the world manages space, so `location_available` needs to be in `world`. 5) I'm also thinking of an alternative viewpoint, where everything in my world is an object-oriented database - where lookups fit nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't understand the problem. """When the agent decides where to move, he checks to make sure he doesn't run into other agents""". Evidently a location can have 0 or 1 agent. Surely the Location class has an agent attribute.

```
locn = self.where_to_move()
if locn.agent is None:
    self.move(locn)
elif locn.agent is self:
    raise ConfusedAgentError()
else:
    self.execute_plan_B()
```

Comment: In my case the main "register" of agents is simply a `list` inside `world` object. In your code, the main "register" of agents is by location, so my problem is indeed solved. But then the other problems comes up: how to do I quickly iterate through all the agents? In your solution the question is then, where do I store that secondary lookup table that allows fast iteration through agents.